# Making the dot in the Theorem normal, but not as like bf

Tags: counters

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{lemma}[something]
test
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to make the DOT after "something" the same font like "something". Please, any suggestions.

Comment: You can define a new `\newtheoremstyle`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use achieve this by using `\newtheoremstyle` macro. A working example is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{newtheorem}% name
{.5\baselineskip \@plus5\p@}% Space above
{.5\baselineskip \@plus5\p@}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount 1
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{\normalfont.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.4em}% Space after theorem head 2
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal'
\theoremstyle{newtheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{lemma}[something]
test
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

The `\normalfont` in the seventh argument makes the dot non-bold.

Answer (score 3):

The standard `\thmhead` command typesets the note/attribution in a group. The easiest way is to remove the group. I added also a differently styled environment to show that the behavior is uniform.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ \the\thm@notefont(#3)}}% no group inside \thmnote
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{lemma}[something]
test
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
test
\end{lemma}

\begin{definition}[something]
test
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clear, quick, perfect! Everything works. Thank you!